# How use async method in FindAsync MongoDb C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

I need get user surname from async repository method and compare with search text, but i don't know how to await it in MongoDb FindAsync method.

```
filtered =(await _orders.FindAsync(async x => (await _userRepository.GetUserById(x.OperatorId))!.Surname.ToLower().Contains(search))).ToList();
```

```
public async Task<User?> GetUserById(string? id)
{
    var res = (await _users.FindAsync(x => x.UserId == id)).FirstOrDefault();
        
    return res is null ? null : EntityConverter.ConvertUser(res); 
}
```

Compiler tell me

> The return type of an 'async' anonymous function must be a 'void', 'Task', 'Task', a task-like type, 'IAsyncEnumerable', or 'IAsyncEnumerator'

My db order model contains ids only (operatorId, masterId). I want get filtered orders list by parametr (operator surname, master surname etc.) and when i get a user(operator or master) to get his surname, i need use await to conwert Task to User, but use await need async lambda. Using async in lambda leads to IDE error (in question). Sorry for my bad eng :3

Comment: Your return type will be your personal model which matches your conditions. I would assume this is a custom class which is not of any async handling type like `Task`. Try removing the prepended `async` inside `FindAsync()` since you are already awaiting every call inside and are only returning a non async model.

Comment: if i remove async, my method GetUserById(async) not work

Comment: Is `GetUserById()` an asynchronous method? could you add that method in your question this will make it easier to see what is going on

Comment: Could you elaborate on what doesnt work if you remove the async from the function? I think that the issue is either: you are returning a bool towards an anonymous async function. Or you are misusing the async keyword inside the lamba statement

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My **db order model contains ids only** (operatorId, masterId). I want get filtered orders list by parametr (operator surname, master surname etc.) and when i get a user(operator or master) to get his surname, i need use **await** to conwert **Task<User>** to **User**, but use await need async lambda. Using async in lambda leads to IDE **error (in question)**. Sorry for my bad eng :3

Answer (score 0):

Use this syntax is you have a few results that fit in memory.

```
List<DBInfo> infoList2 = await collection.Find(_ => _.type == "DB").ToListAsync();
```

Find more examples here
https://github.com/iso8859/learn-mongodb-by-example/tree/main/dotnet